# Is paraatma microBrahman living beside atma or it is Brahman himself present metaphysically beside atma?

Tags: brahman, atma

All of us know that para-atma present beside atma as a witness, the question is: are para-atmas microtheoi present beside atmas or all para-atmas are one entity, i.e: Brahman, present metaphysically beside the atmas?.

Comment: Only dvaita siddhanta says it. Not all

Comment: There are no many paramatmas. There is only one paramatma in all living beings or individual atmas.

Comment: There is only One. From our perspective It may appear different, but It is not. There is no metaphysical or physical, there is only the One Existence. From our perspective, it appears as metaphysical and physical.