# What is a para-aatmaa?

Tags: atma, paramatma

Hinduism believes in the highest concept of supreme soul called as Param-Atma.

I have doubt if there is something called as Para-Atma in Hindu religion?

Comment: Possibly Duplicate - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37385/is-paraatma-microbrahman-living-beside-atma-or-it-is-brahman-himself-present-met

Comment: where from you got the term para-atma?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the relation/difference between Brahman(ब्रह्म) & Parabrahm(परब्रह्म)?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9617/what-is-the-relation-difference-between-brahman%e0%a4%ac%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%b9%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%ae-parabrahm%e0%a4%aa%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%ac%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0%e0%a4%b9%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%ae)